# How to set cpu priority between uiwebviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

I have 2 webview on screen and both loads heavy requests (local js works). Can I set priority between these two webview. Can I say first is low priority and second one is high priority (first one can use %30- cpu, second %100 etc.)

Comment: You can't do this using CPU priority, this is not possible. What you can do is to implement the delegate and load one and start the the second only after the first webview finish loading or after some loading, no CPU handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as cpu-priorisation for iOS. iOS handles this task by itself. You don't have access to that kind of settings.